# How to remove all special characters except for some, using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this string: "!#€f#$#"
I want to use regex to remove all special characters at the beginning and the end and stop when i encounter the first character that's excluded.lets say the characters ["$", "€"] are excluded, the result should be "€f#$". Also, i have different lists of characters that are excluded from the beginning and different at the end.

```py
text = "!#€f#$#"
newtext = re.sub("\W*$", "", text)
```

This only affects the ending characters and it removes ALL specials without exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
text = "!#€f#$#"
newtext = re.sub(r"^[^\w$€]+|[^\w$€]+$", "", text)
print(newtext)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2KvJWG)

**Details**

- `^[^\w$€]+` - start of string (`^`) and 1 or more chars other than word chars, `$` and €`(`[^\w$€]+`)
- `|` - or
- `[^\w$€]+$` - 1 or more chars other than word chars, `$` and €`and end of string (`$`).